# Delphi 11.2 Speedbuttons don't show border at design time

Tags: delphi, button

Running windows 10 21H2. Just upgraded to Delphi 11.2 (from 11.1).
Speedbuttons (with Flat=False) do not show the button rectangle at design time. It does appear at runtime.
Most/all of our VCL projects have an empty style name. I have noticed that if I set the Stylename for the button (or even the form), then it shows normally. But is this the best way of handling it? Is there a global setting somewhere that can restore "normal" behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should [report to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com)

Comment: Yes, you can disable VCL styles in the form designer. RSP-39534

Comment: @Remy Someone already has apparently (RSP-39534) and the advice there is as per Uwe's answer. (I Searched QC but couldn't find it myself). Thanks for prompt response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 11.2 the Form Designer Options have a new option *Mimic the system style*, which is active by default. Disabling that should solve your problem.

[Form Designer Options](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Form_Designer_Options)

Comment: Brilliant. I did see a reference to that a week or so back before I knew it was going to be relevant, and then I couldn't find it again. Thank you.